# VS code image viewer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library, settings

I just started using VS code. I'm working on pillow module in python. I want to show my picture in windows default viewer but my picture opens in VS code viewer. How can I set windows viewer as the main viewer? or generally how can I change image viewer in VS code?? I need an immediate answer to continue my project.
thanks a lot!

I tryed to change VS code settings but I couldn't find appropriate items in settings.

Answer (score 0):

The file opened by Pillow is opened in **.png** format, and you can modify the default application in Windows.

Select Start > Settings > Apps > Default apps.

Search **.png** and choose the **Windows Photos**.

[image]